# value too great for base (error token is "3ApplicationDesktop")

Tags: bash

My simple bash program is giving the error stated in the title.

```
#!/bin/sh

num1=$1
whatOperator=$2
num2=$3

echo Answer: $(($num1$whatOperator$num2))
```

I have tried adding 10#

```
echo Answer: $((10#$num1$whatOperator$num2))
```

as said to do when  I have looked this up, but then it gives this error:

```
value too great for base (error token is "10#3ApplicationsDesktop")
```

I was wondering if anybody knows what my problem was and how to fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a space between:

```
echo "Answer: $(($num1 $whatOperator $num2))"
```

Only integers are allowed. And the operators you can use are:

```
    **              exponentiation
    *, /, %         multiplication, division, remainder
    +, -            addition, subtraction
    <<, >>          left and right bitwise shifts
    <=, >=, <, >    comparison
    ==, !=          equality, inequality
    &               bitwise AND
    ^               bitwise XOR
    |               bitwise OR
    &&              logical AND
    ||              logical OR
```

See `help let`.

> I managed to solve my problem but, I don't know why it is fixed.
>
> calc 3 * 3
>
> gives an error but if I enter
>
> calc 3*3
>
> it works perfectly.

Because `*` expands as a glob pattern (try `echo *`) and `3*3` did not match any file so it stayed the way it is literally that your code worked. You should quote glob patterns:

```
calc 3 '*' 3
calc 3 "*" 3
calc 3 \* 3
calc 3 $'*' 3
```

Comment: That just gave me another error but I found out that removing spaces in the arguments removes any errors.

Comment: +konsolebox is there a way to put that fix in the code?

Comment: @user3726628 No. It can only be fixed within the context of the caller as it is the caller that expands arguments and produces those commands.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem but, I don't know why it is fixed.

```
calc 3 * 3
```

gives an error but if I enter

```
calc 3*3
```

it works perfectly.
Even though I solved the error I was wondering if anybody knows why it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The `10#` should be added before `$num1` and `$num2`. `10#` is useful in case where one of your integers starts with a 0 (example: 10#012 = 12, instead of 012 = 10).
But I think that is not your problem: Looking at the error message you gave, I am pretty sure variables `whatOperator` and `num2` are not what you expect.

Try adding `set -xv` at the beginning of the script and `set +xv` at the end ; or `echo "whatOperator=$whatOperator. and num2=$num2."` (the dots used to delimit the string, to easily see whether there is a line break). *I predict `whatOperator=Applications. and num2=Desktop.`*

I would review the call of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @konsolebox's answer, the following bash function might prove useful:

```
function [[[ () {
  lhs=$(printf '%07.3f' "$1"); lhs=${lhs/./}
  rhs=$(printf '%07.3f' "$3"); rhs=${rhs/./}
  case "$2" in
    -lt) return $(( 10#$lhs < 10#$rhs )) ;;
    -le) return $(( 10#$lhs <= 10#$rhs )) ;;
    -eq) return $(( 10#$lhs == 10#$rhs )) ;;
    -ge) return $(( 10#$lhs >= 10#$rhs )) ;;
    -gt) return $(( 10#$lhs > 10#$rhs )) ;;
  esac
}
```

Usage might go something like:

```
n=0.83
if [[[ $n -gt 1 ]]]; then
  # do something
fi
```

Note that the trailing `]]]` is ignored.